# Is there any way in Tkinter entry box to replace comma with dot?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is there any way to replace comma with dot in Tkinter entry box?
For example, if the the user types comma (,) it will appear a dot on the screen.

Comment: you can bind function to `<Key>` event  (or `<KeyRelease>` can be more useful) and it can change text in Entry after every clicked key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bind function to Entry with `<KeyRelease-comma>` event. It will run this function **after** it put comman in `Entry` and then function can get text from `Entry and replace with new text which has dot instead of comma.

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback(event):
    print('event.widget.get():', event.widget.get())
    text = event.widget.get()     # get all text
    text = text.replace(',', '.') # replace comma
    event.widget.delete(0, 'end') # remove all text from Entry
    event.widget.insert(0, text)  # put new text in Entry


root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.bind('<KeyRelease-comma>', callback)

root.mainloop()
```

If you use `<Key-comma>` then function will be executed **before** `tkinter` put char in `Entry` so you get text without comma and you can't change it.

---

You can use `StringVar()` in `Entry(..., textvariable=...)` and assing function to `StringVar`. `trace('w', ...)` will execute function when `tkinter` changes (set) text in `StringVar`.

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback(id_, mode, other):
    #print(id_, mode, other)
    var.set( var.get().replace(',', '.') )


root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.StringVar()
var.trace('w', callback)

e = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)
e.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** using `<Key-comma>` you can execute function **before** `tkitner` put comma in Entry. Function can put dot and use `return "break"` to stop event and it will not put comma in `Entry`

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback(event):
    #print('event.widget.get():', event.widget.get())
    event.widget.insert('end', '.')  # put new text in Entry
    return 'break' # stop event so it will not put comma in Entry

root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.bind('<Key-comma>', callback) # execute callback before it puts comma in Entry

root.mainloop()
```